# How to change the path of background-image in css modules of Next.js v14 when dev and build

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, css-modules, next.js14

I am using Next.js v14 to create a page with the configuration in the attached image.

[image]

In `index.module.scss`, I am using an image for the background.

Below is a portion of the code.

```
    &::before {
        left: 0;
        background: url(/img/pc/index_hero_bg1.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
    }

    &::after {
        right: 0;
        background: url(/img/pc/index_hero_bg2.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
    }
```

The image specified in `url` is in `/public/img`, so the image path in `url` starts at `/img`.

I want to change the path of `url` in `index.module.scss` in `npm run dev` and `npm run build`.

The `dev` is `localhost:3000`, so I can leave it as it is, but for the `build` I want it to be on the second level `sampledomain.com/path-to-site/`.

No search, no blog post, and no answer using Chat GPT.

For example, the answer was to put the environment variable in front of the path, but I get an error.

Also, I don't know how to configure `webpack` in `next.config.js`, because I have no knowledge of `webpack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define the asset prefix in your next.config.js file.

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/path-to-site', // This sets the base path for your application
  assetPrefix: '/path-to-site/', // This sets the asset prefix for your assets
};
```

in your SCSS file, you can reference the background images

```
&::before {
    left: 0;
    background: url('/img/pc/index_hero_bg1.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
}

&::after {
    right: 0;
    background: url('/img/pc/index_hero_bg2.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

edit:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/path-to-site', // This sets the base path for your application
  assetPrefix: '/path-to-site/', // This sets the asset prefix for your assets
  sassOptions: {
    prependData: `
      $assetPrefix: '${process.env.ASSET_PREFIX}';
    `,
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I tried adding `basePath` / `assetPrefix`, but the image path in the built css file was the same as the scss file.
If this is correct, it should be changed to `assetPrefix`+`/img`.

Comment: in that case, you can manually adjust the paths in your SCSS file to include the assetPrefix
background: url('#{$assetPrefix}/img/pc/index_hero_bg1.png') 0 0 repeat-x;

Comment: What does it mean?
When I change the path to `url('#{$assetPrefix}/img/pc/index_hero_bg1.png')`, I get the error message `SassError: Undefined variable.`
I understand that I cannot reference the `assetPrefix` from the scss file under normal circumstances.
Is there any special way to do this?

Comment: One common approach is to define a SCSS variable in your JavaScript code and pass it to your SCSS file during compilation. (check the updated answer)

Comment: I understood that `prependData` is an option for `webpack sass-loader`.
`prependData` was seems like change to `additionalData` but, both worked fine.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: if it worked, you can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables will not work if you put them in front of the path because they are primarily designed to run with js file. However, you can still make use of it by importing an empty component with css using environment variable as condition.

First you will need to place the css of two environments into two separated css files (`localBackground.css` and `buildBackground.css`)

Then, you will need two empty components that do nothing but import the css file (`BackgroundLocal.tsx` and `BackgroundBuild.tsx`). The content of these two files can simply be like below:

```
/*for the local */
import "./localBackground.css";   // your css file path
export default function BackgroundLocal() {
  return <></>;
}

/*for the build*/
import "./buildBackground.css";   // your css file path
export default function BackgroundBuild() {
  return <></>;
}
```

After this, you will need to dynamically import these two files with condition checking based on environment variables:

```
"use client"
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
...
const DynamicBgL = dynamic(() => import("@/components/BackgroundLocal"), {
  ssr: false,
});
const DynamicBgB = dynamic(() => import("@/components/BackgroundBuild"), {
  ssr: false,
});

/*IsLocal is a environment variable which will be `true` for local development and `false` for build*/
const DynamicBG = process.env.IsLocal ? DynamicBgL : DynamicBgB;
...
export default function MainPage(){
  return(
        ...
    <DynamicBG/>
    ...
}
```

Hope this can help!